# Change WIFI-hotspot protocol on Xiaomi, possible?

Tags: hotspot, 802.11ac

Is there a way to change a setting on the Xiaomi 6a to produce a hotspot using a different protocol? other than 802.11**ac**?

I'm lost on this. My Surface RT (yes I know...) can't see the Wifi network created by my Xiaomi 6a because it is **802.11ac**, and -ac- is not supported by it, anyway I can see all the other networks around my house. I also tried to use Bluetooth internet sharing but it didn't work. Everything else works, and I can use the WIFI and Bluetooth internet sharing on diff computers, it's just the incompabilitiy between those two.

- I could buy a cheap wifi usb dongle, but that's my last option (bulky)
- Change phone... no way
- Drop the Surface (nope, it's useful for something here)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved? I don't know what happened. My Surface RT was unable to see my network on the Xiaomi hotspot (just my phone), AC by the way. After researching on the web found specific info stating it was not compatible with 802.11ac.

But today a couple of updates were installed and now it works, the updates say nothing but "security" and "office" names related, so I don't have exactly specifics directly related to my issue, it simply works.